# products image upload error after upload 100%

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, server-setup

when i upload product image he is complete 100% after error and there is no error show then i write this code in

> /lib/Varien/File/uploader.php 
>   after not show any error and permission is right

```
public function save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null){
$this->_validateFile();
 if ($this->_allowCreateFolders) {
 $this->_createDestinationFolder($destinationFolder);
} 
if (!is_writable($destinationFolder)) {
// Put a mage::log() and check what is the folder magento is looking for.
Mage::log($destinationFolder);
throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');}
```

[image: product image error after 100% uploading]

Comment: admin is https or http ? https has some issue in firefox. It is working in chrome

Comment: admin is http and i purchage a dedicated server i think issue in server because my every magento site same issue and permission is right because i am upload image in cms block but i can't image in product please help me

Comment: might be there is some issue with flex uploader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue at **media folder permission**,**Webserver**`( like www-data))` user does not have *rewrite  permission at media folder*`(yourMagentoDir/media)`.You need to give write permission to Webserver

*So,You need to discuss this  thing with Hosting provider and they will help you for resolve this issue.*