# Image Upload goes 100% and then I get an error in red and asks me to Remove file

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload, ce-1.9.2.0

I am having the exact same problem as stated here:
"[products image upload error after upload 100%](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/102083/38863)"

I am trying to upload images to an already existing Magento website, my images go 100% and then I get an error in red asking to remove the images. I have followed most of the tutorial I could find online, all my `media/` and `var/` folder have 777 permission, I have php5-gd installed on my server, the baseurl and secureurl is set properly.

Last time I have had this problem I had a hired a freelancer to resolve it, he told me, varnish setting had issues but didn't give me details.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your project open the file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php and put a Mage::log() inside the save() function.

public function save($destinationFolder, $newFileName = null)
    {
        $this->_validateFile();

```
    if ($this->_allowCreateFolders) {
        $this->_createDestinationFolder($destinationFolder);
    }

    if (!is_writable($destinationFolder)) {
        // Put a mage::log() and check what is the folder magento is looking for.
        Mage::log($destinationFolder);
        throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');
    }
```

. . . . .

}

From the log you can find out the folder which Magento is looking for. And then check permissions for that folder.

Comment: Link to exception.log http://pastebin.com/x4SxkrwS and system.log http://pastebin.com/DQKC2aiB

Comment: Hey @keshav can you please look into the logs I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't solve it I ended posting this error on Upwork [website](https://www.upwork.com/job/Magento-Image-Upload-Issue_~0133936476cbfa2dde/). The issue was in lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php someone/ perhaps me or the earlier programmer had by mistakenly put the content before opening

Anyways learnt the lesson the hard way. I don't know if this qualify's as an answer. Plus it wasn't solving the problem till the time this freelancer cleared the /opcache sitting in the root folder of my Magento installation.

Comment: any update on your situation? how you resolved?